# Get array of Date for each user grouped by $dayOfWeek and operation on it in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to aggregate my data and make an array with multiple stored date, grouped by user and day of week and for this day, something like for this data (according we are february, the 24th) :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b0b4b732d3cd188cea9e1b"),
    "user" : 1,
    "heure" : ISODate("2017-02-24T22:33:27.858Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b0b4b732d3cd188cea9e1b"),
    "user" : 1,
    "heure" : ISODate("2017-02-24T23:33:27.858Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b0b4b732d3cd188cea9e1b"),
    "user" : 2,
    "heure" : ISODate("2017-02-24T22:34:27.858Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b0b4b732d3cd188cea9e1b"),
    "user" : 1,
    "heure" : ISODate("2017-02-25T07:21:27.858Z")
}
```

Get this :

```
{
    "_id" : {user : 1, jour : 55}
    "date" : [ISODate("2017-02-24T22:33:27.858Z"), ISODate("2017-02-24T23:33:27.858Z") ]
}
{
    "_id" : {user : 2, jour : 55}
    "date" : [ISODate("2017-02-24T22:34:27.858Z") ] 
}
```

I tried using $push of $match, but everything failed.

Optionally, i want to have the time beetween time two date, like for user 1, adding another field which contains 1 hours. But i don't wan't to use ate at most once, so with 4 date in array, i need to have only a addition : the value of first and second with the value of third and fourth. I want to see this to learn how to use the $cond properly

Here is my actual pipeline :

```
[
      { $match : {$eq : [{$dayOfYear : "$heure"}, {$dayOfYear : ISODate()}] } 
      {
        $group : {
           _id : {
               user : "$user", 

           },
           date : {$push: "$heure"},
           nombre: { $sum : 1 }
        }
      }
   ]
```

For now, i don't handle the second part of the aggregate function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first filter part you need to use **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** pipeline as it will return all documents that match the condition with the **[`$$KEEP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#keep)** system variable returned by **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** based on the **[`$dayOfYear`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfYear/#exp._S_dayOfYear)** date operator and discards documents otherwise with **[`$$PRUNE`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#prune)**.

Consider composing your final aggregate pipeline as:

```
[
    {
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                {
                    "$eq": [
                        { "$dayOfYear": "$heure" },
                        { "$dayOfYear": new Date() }
                    ]
                },
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "user": "$user",
                "jour": { "$dayOfYear": "$heure" }
            },
            "date": { "$push": "$heure" },
            "nombre": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot. Do you know a way to make the second part in just on request, or i have to make another one ?